# How to render and select tiles from a huge plane in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, optimization

I have a situation that I need help with. I have one big plane that is separated into 300k+ square tiles (and sometimes bezier curves). The whole plane is visible in the screen.

If I do a canvas draw only once, the rendering takes a bit of time (1-2s in a modern laptop) but it is doable. However, I need a way to select certain tiles by mousing over them, and selecting them (multiple with drag and drop). I have the logic for mouse position in place and I can find which tile is in which position by redrawing the scene and doing something like:

```
if (!found && context.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0);'
    found = true; // for most scenarios, this stops the expensive operations that is isPointInPath.
} else {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(240, 240, 240);'
}
```

The problem arises when I try to find the hovered tile in 300k+ tile space because the time it takes to find the mouse is very slow (3-4 seconds) and the lag gives a bad user experience.

Currently, I am toying around with creating a tree structure where non-leaf nodes of the tree are bigger size nodes (e.g first node splits the plane into four shapes, the next one splits the smaller ones into four shapes; kind of like a Quadtree structure). However, I have been confused about how to split this tree into this many pieces when I have bezier curves. I can't just split the tree into four squares because some of the tiles will overlap. My main question is how to handle those edge cases where tiles overlap in between two parent nodes.

Or a bit more general question. Is there a better way to manage this problem than going with tree route?

Comment: I think the Quadtree is the best solution here. Maybe [Daniel Shiffman's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJxEcs0w_kE) may give you some ideas.

Comment: Except for the bezier curve part (with which we don't have enough information), couldn't you just floor-divide `mouseX` by the width of a small square, and do the same for y? That would be the column and row of the hovered square.